# Efficient way to access JWT data from Controllers

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 5.4 with a custom authenticator which reads & validates a JWT with each request.

Inside the JWT is data which I need accessible in the controller.

Rather than re-read the JWT in the controller, I'd like to store the decoded data, or even 1 element of that data, so that it doesn't need to be re-read in a controller.

What is an efficient way to access data detected in an authenticator, so it is available in the context of a controller action?

Comment: Why not implement a service and access it anywhere you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement service for this in Symfony, which should be something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class JWTInterceptor
{
    protected $request;

    protected $data;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        // Get JWT token from request header, decode and store it in $this->data
    }

    // Get decoded data
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

And in your controller just use Dependency Injection to insert the service and call `JWTInterceptor::getData()` to use decoded data.

There should be other approach as well, like using `EventListener or EventSubscriber` or implement a root/base controller with relevant methods and make it accessible to all child controllers etc.

Or if you are using https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle it already comes packaged with events so you can modify as per your need.

Comment: Just using the Firebase JWT lib. I prefer less "magic" and this solution is perfect. Thank you.